# How to join multiple documents?

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, join, iqueryable

I want to join multiple documents in MongoDB. I have used following code, but it isn't working. Did I do any think wrong?. I have added base entity model which contains Id.

```
var products = _productRepository.GetCollection(_dbContext);
var prodWarhoseMapping = _productWarehouseMapRepository.GetCollection(_dbContext);
var warhouses = _warehouseRepository.GetCollection(_dbContext);

public class Product:BaseEntity
{
    public string product_code { get; set; }
    public decimal fat_tax { get; set; }
}

public class ProductWarehouseMap :BaseEntity
{
    public ObjectId product_id { get; set; }
    public ObjectId warehouse_id { get; set; }
    public int qty { get; set; }
    public decimal price { get; set; }
}
public class Warehouse :BaseEntity
{
    public ObjectId supplier_id { get; set; }
    public string warehouse_code { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
    public string street_address { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string postal_code { get; set; }
    public string region { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public string manager_name { get; set; }
    public string fax { get; set; }
}

//works proper
var query1 = (from p in products
            join pm in prodWarhoseMapping on p._id equals pm.product_id
                        select new
                        {
                            Products = p,
                            ProductMapping = pm,
                        }).ToList();

//Getting error 
var query = (from p in products
    join pm in prodWarhoseMapping on p._id equals pm.product_id
    join wh in warhouses on pm.warehouse_id equals wh._id
    select new
    {
         Products = p,
         ProductMapping = pm,
         Warehouse = wh
     }).ToList();
```

**Bellow is the base entity** 
I forgot to add base entity model

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
    public ObjectId _id { get; set; }

}
```

**Bellow is error message**

Expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Project.Communication.EntityModels.ProductWarehouseMap]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Project.Communication.EntityModels.ProductWarehouseMap]' of method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Project.Communication.EntityModels.ProductWarehouseMap] Where[ProductWarehouseMap](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Project.Communication.EntityModels.ProductWarehouseMap], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[Project.Communication.EntityModels.ProductWarehouseMap,System.Boolean]])'
Parameter name: arg0

Comment: We'll need more than *Getting error* to help you, e.g. the error message / code. Also the `_id` property is nowhere to be seen in your class definitions.

Comment: @KeyurPATEL Plz check above code i have added base entity model which contains id.

Comment: Once again, the error message / code would be helpful, the `_id` definition looks good.

Comment: @KeyurPATEL i have added error message. Plz check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message makes it seem `Where` is used, but it isn't (assuming the code you are showing is exactly what you tried compiling). Nevertheless, you can try some variations such as

Performing Select() in memory using IEnumerable:

```
var query = (from p in products
    join pm in prodWarhoseMapping on p._id equals pm.product_id
    join wh in warhouses on pm.warehouse_id equals wh._id)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(s => new 
    {
         Products = p,
         ProductMapping = pm,
         Warehouse = wh
    }).ToList();
```

Or using `AsQueryable()`

```
var query = (from p in products.AsQueryable()
    join pm in prodWarhoseMapping.AsQueryable() on p._id equals pm.product_id
    join wh in warhouses.AsQueryable() on pm.warehouse_id equals wh._id
    select new
    {
         Products = p,
         ProductMapping = pm,
         Warehouse = wh
    }).ToList();
```

EDIT: the above approaches will take very long and use a lot of memory if the data sets are huge.

In order to find the underlying cause, could you try this query and let me know what it returns:

```
var query2 = (from pm in prodWarhoseMapping
        join wh in warhouses on pm.warehouse_id equals wh._id
                    select new
                    {
                        ProductMapping = pm,
                        Warehouse = wh,                            
                    }).ToList();
```

Comment: Your answer is correct but,Product and ProdWarhoseMapping table may have data in lacks and i need to add more join also. Then it will work proper or any memory related issue will come?

Comment: If you mean lakhs, yes it may be a problem using this approach. We'll need to find the underlying cause and fix that. Try the code I added by edit and let me know if it works, it will help for debugging.